# I want to summarize on a table

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
Array ( 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [poidsTot] => 1 
        [idBout] => 1 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [poidsTot] => 2 
        [idBout] => 1 
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [poidsTot] => 2 
        [idBout] => 2 
    ) 
    [4] => Array ( 
        [poidsTot] => 8 
        [idBout] => 2 
    ) 
)
```

This is a table containing several arrays with two values ​​each. The value1 is a weight and the value2 is an identifier. I want to sum all the weights with the same identifier. help. thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this data being retrieved from a SQL database?

Comment: Yes these data are stored in an array type field in one of the tables of my given database

Comment: Then use your SQL query to do this via SUM() and GROUP BY: `SELECT idBout, SUM(poidsTot) AS total FROM tablename GROUP BY idBout`

Answer (score 0):

$newarr is a new array of sum

```
$newarr = array();
foreach($a as $onea)
{
    $newarr[$onea['idBout']]+= $onea['poidsTot'];
}
```

which results in:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 10
)
```

https://eval.in/776652

Comment: thanks i did this                                      $cetteTarifica = $content['tarification'];
  $newarr = array();
  foreach($cetteTarifica as $onea)
  {
   $newarr[$onea['idBout']]+= $onea['poidsTot'];
  }
  print_r($newarr);
  die();

Comment: Make sure your array is peroperly structured and matches the values in the foreach loop. Show me the full code if possible (use eval.in, it's nice)

Comment: $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $thisCommande = $em->getRepository('OCCommandesBundle:Commandes')->find($commande->getContent());
  $content = $thisCommande->getCommande();
  $cetteTarifica = $content['tarification'];
  $newarr = array();
  foreach($cetteTarifica as $onea)
  {
   $newarr[$onea['idBout']]+=$onea['poidsTot'];
  }
  print_r($newarr);
  die();

Comment: it is is a symfony3 project

Comment: I need to see the structure of $cetteTarifica array, please use eval.in to show me.